# Mass-energy equivalence in Nuclear Reactions

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy

During nuclear reactions, energy is either released or absorbed by the nuclei. In a text which I was reading, it is written that the energy (if released) comes from a decrease in mass of the reactant nuclei, and if absorbed increases the mass of the reactant nuclei to form the product nuclei.
Can this be explained by $E= mc^2$? And is mass really "converted" into energy as written in this text:
"The lost mass in the nuclear reaction is converted into the kinetic energy of the nuclei present after the collision"

Comment: There is nothing special about nuclear reactions.  The same mass-energy relationship exists in chemical reactions - a charged battery has more mass than a discharged battery.  A stretched spring has more mass than an unstretched spring.  It just measurable in nuclear reactions.

Comment: That is correct, but is mass really "convertible" into energy? Because if it were so it would imply that both are separate entities.

Comment: The lost mass not only converted into kinetic energy of the nuclei but also in the form of photons released in the form of electromagnetic waves.